# regex split data line into fields

Tags: regex, hive

In hive, if I have a line of data that I want to split into 4 fields based on some regexp (for example `"34,56 43--21"` to  `34, 56, 43, 21`) and the table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE example (f1 INT, f2 INT, f3 INT, f4 INT);
```

is there a way to give it the location of the file and automatically have it split every line into the table based on the regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex serde to define the pattern.  The parts in parenthesis should be extracted.

```
CREATE external TABLE if not exists example (f1 INT, f2 INT, f3 INT, f4 INT)
 row format serde
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerde'
   with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(\\d*)\\,(\\d*)\\s(\\d*)\\-{2}(\\d*)")
```

If this doesn't work change the hyphen from "\-" to just "-" but I think it needs to be escaped twice.  Sorry i can't test right now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do

```
LOAD DATA INPATH ‘/path/on/hdfs/file_name.csv’ OVERWRITE INTO TABLE example1;
```

http://wise.ajou.ac.kr/mata/load-csv-file-to-hive-hadoop/
Assuming you have your columns correct. Keep in mind, this will overwrite the entire table. I guess if you want to append, your best bet would be to make a new table and then find a way to merge it.

Comment: Hi, I'm fine overwriting, but unfortunately my data isn't in csv format though. I'm trying to split it based on some regexp I have.

Comment: How big is your file? It might be easier to simply use another language for speed and simplicity purposes